# Error 401 - Unauthorized Excel VBA Web Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a secured (https) website. The code works but returns Error 401 saying, `The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field`. I've googled for a while without any success. [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57bc1d5f-f0d2-4699-8762-1ca8a1d30909/serverxmlhttp-returns-401-error-in-excel-vba) site seems to have an answer but I don't fully understand it or know how to implement it. Any help is appreciated. See code below.

```
Public Sub TestMyXML()

    Dim objXMLPage As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim objHTMLDocument As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim objHTMLElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set objXMLPage = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    objXMLPage.Open "GET", "[Specific page on secure website - Yes, it's accurate]", False
    objXMLPage.send
    objHTMLDocument.body.innerHTML = objXMLPage.responseText

    ProcessHTMLPage objHTMLDocument

End Sub

Public Sub ProcessHTMLPage(ByRef htmlPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim objHTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim objHTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim objHTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set objHTMLTables = htmlPage.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each objHTMLTable In objHTMLTables
        Debug.Print objHTMLTable.className
        For Each objHTMLRow In objHTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Debug.Print objHTMLRow.innerText & vbTab
        Next objHTMLRow
    Next objHTMLTable

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the code works. Just add the following libraries:

- Microsoft XML, v6.0
- Microsoft HTML Object Library

But, obviously the site being tried, **does not like being scraped**, thus it throws 401 error. I have replaced with a "random" website (And changed the `table` and `tr` tags) and it works:

```
Public Sub TestMyXML()

    Dim objXMLPage As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim objHTMLDocument As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim objHTMLElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set objXMLPage = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    objXMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.vitoshacademy.com/all", False
    objXMLPage.send
    objHTMLDocument.body.innerHTML = objXMLPage.responseText

    ProcessHTMLPage objHTMLDocument

End Sub

Public Sub ProcessHTMLPage(ByRef htmlPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim objHTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim objHTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim objHTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set objHTMLTables = htmlPage.getElementsByTagName("ul")
    For Each objHTMLTable In objHTMLTables
        Debug.Print objHTMLTable.className
        For Each objHTMLRow In objHTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("li")
            Debug.Print objHTMLRow.innerText & vbTab
        Next objHTMLRow
    Next objHTMLTable

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there no way to include a `WWW-Authenticate header field`? Seems like that's what it wants.

Comment: @Brian - I have a feeling, that you are trying to cralw a website like this one - `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`, which requires some kind of authentication before - e.g., login with password and username into your google account. How to do the authentication, in order to login correctly - honestly, I do not know and I doubt that a nice web site will allow it through VBA. After all, this is one of the reasons why these pictures with "I am not a robot" checkmark exist.

Comment: @Brian the solution is to use a REST API, if one exists.scraping web content like you're doing is very often explicitly against the terms of service of websites. For example if you tried scraping Stack Overflow that way, you'd quickly get yourself into an IP ban.

Comment: @Vityata I am not trying to do that.